# Usage of shared memory between 2 processes in c socket client program leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, sockets, shared-memory

I'm creating a client program that has 2 processes: a parent process that transmits data to the server periodically to let it know the client is still connected, and a child process that receives user input and sends it to the server, and if that input happens to be "#EXIT" then the child process will let the parent process know that the program needs to terminate via a variable in shared memory, and then exit. The problem is that I'm getting a segmentation fault before the program even prints anything.

The strange thing is that the first time I ran it, it gave the expected output and terminated when I typed "#EXIT", but all subsequent times I ran it, it just immediately seg faulted. At first I thought it was because I didn't call `shm_unlink` at the end, but I added that and the result was the same. I then thought it was because I didn't call `exit` on the child process, but I added that and again the result was the same.

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc-1 != 2){
        perror("Usage: ./351ChatClient [address] [port]");
        return -1;
    }

    int sock = 0, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char buffer[1024] = {0};

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form 
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }

    int* shared_memory;

    int shm_fd = shm_open("Transmitting", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);

    ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(int));

    shared_memory = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    shared_memory[0] = 0;

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0){
        char data[256];
        while (strcmp(data, "#EXIT") != 0){
            fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin);
            data[strlen(data)-1] = '\0';
            send(sock , data, strlen(data) , 0 );
            valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
            printf("%s\n",buffer );
        }
        shared_memory[0] = 1;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
     }
    else if (pid > 0){
        while(shared_memory[0] == 0){
            // transmit data every couple seconds to let server know client is still connected
        }
        shm_unlink("Transmitting");
        printf("Stopped transmitting\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> //For Sockets
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> //For the AF_INET (Address Family)
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXSIZE 256

void add_user(char name[], char password[]){
    if (strlen(name) > MAXSIZE || strlen(password) > MAXSIZE){
        // send error message to client
        return;
    }

    FILE* fp = fopen("users.txt", "a");
    char s[strlen(name)+strlen(password)+2];
    strcpy(s, name);
    strcat(s, "\n");
    strcat(s, password);
    strcat(s, "\n");
    fputs(s, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void connect_user(char name[], char password[]){

    FILE* fp = fopen("users.txt", "r");

    char line[MAXSIZE];
    char cur_name[MAXSIZE];

    bool match = false;

    int line_no = 1;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){

        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0'; // remove trailing newline

        if (line_no % 2 != 0){

            strcpy(cur_name, line);

            if (strcmp(cur_name, name) == 0){
                match = true;
            }

        }
        else if(match){

            if (strcmp(line, password) == 0){
                char s[strlen(cur_name)+strlen(" is entering the queue\n")];
                strcpy(s, cur_name);
                strcat(s, " is entering the queue\n");
                printf("%s", s);
                // add user to the queue
                return;
            }
            else{
                // send invalid password message to client
                return;
            }
        }
        line_no = line_no + 1;
    }
    add_user(name, password); // if user not found, add it to the DB 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE* fp = fopen("users.txt", "a"); // creates users file if it does not exist
    fclose(fp);

    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
         perror("ERROR opening socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        perror("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd, 5);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    //Below code is modified to handle multiple clients using fork
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    int pid;
    while (1) {
         newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
         if (newsockfd < 0)
              perror("ERROR on accept");
         //fork new process
         pid = fork();
         if (pid < 0) {
              perror("ERROR in new process creation");
         }
         if (pid == 0) {
            //child process
            close(sockfd);
            //do whatever you want
            bzero(buffer, 256);
            while(strcmp(buffer, "#EXIT") != 0){

                memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); // clear the read buffer

                n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
                if (n < 0)
                    perror("ERROR reading from socket");
                printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);

                n = write(newsockfd, "I got your message", 18);
                if (n < 0)
                    perror("ERROR writing to socket");
            }
            n = write(newsockfd, "See you soon!", 18);
            if (n < 0)
                perror("ERROR writing to socket");
            printf("Closing connection with client");
            close(newsockfd);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
          } else {
             //parent process
             close(newsockfd);
          }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
   return 0;
}
```

The output I expect to receive when I type "#EXIT" is

```
#EXIT
Stopped transmitting
```

But the output I receive is simply

```
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Before I get the chance to type anything.

I'm new to c sockets and c in general, so please don't hesitate to point out if I'm doing anything else completely wrong. Thank you.

EDIT: Another thing I noticed is that when the client segfaults, the server receives a significant number of messages. Not sure why though.

EDIT 2: I commented out all the socket code in my client, recompiled it, and executed it, and the segmentation fault still happened.

EDIT 3: I fixed the while loop checking `data` before it is defined, but the issue still persists.

Here is the simplified client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc-1 != 2){
        perror("Usage: ./351ChatClient [address] [port]");
        return -1;
    }

    int* shared_memory;

    int shm_fd = shm_open("Transmitting", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);

    ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(int));

    shared_memory = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    shared_memory[0] = 0;

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0){
        char data[256];
        while (true){
            fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin);
            data[strlen(data)-1] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(data, "#EXIT") != 0)
                break;  
        }
        shared_memory[0] = 1;
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
     }
    else if (pid > 0){
        while(shared_memory[0] == 0){
            // transmit data every couple seconds to let server know client is still connected
        }
        shm_unlink("Transmitting");
        printf("Stopped transmitting\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 4: I ran the client through valgrind using the command `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./351ChatClient 127.0.0.1 8080` and this is what I got:

```
==11098== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11098== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11098== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11098== Command: ./351ChatClient 127.0.0.1 8080
==11098== 
==11098== Invalid write of size 4
==11098==    at 0x108AA4: main (in /home/jp/Courses/csci351/projects/project1/351ChatClient)
==11098==  Address 0xffffffffffffffff is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==11098== 
==11098== 
==11098== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==11098==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
==11098==    at 0x108AA4: main (in /home/jp/Courses/csci351/projects/project1/351ChatClient)
==11098==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==11098==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==11098==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==11098==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==11098==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==11098== 
==11098== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11098==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11098==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==11098== 
==11098== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11098== 
==11098== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11098== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: you need to share the other side's code as well. I don't think there is an odd thing.

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve] and the backtrace at the point of the segfault. In particular, first remove all the socket code from your example so that you can really assert the shared memory is the problem.

Comment: Thank you Ulrich, I did as you said and I can confirm that the segfault is caused by the shared memory code.

Comment: @jipthechip Put also simplified code which is discussed in _EDIT 2_ in addition to other 2 codes.

Comment: `while (strcmp(data, "#EXIT") != 0)` invokes undefined behavior the first loop iteration since `data` is not initialized.

Comment: Have you executed the code via valgrind?

Comment: @JeffHolt his valgrind answer says what I say already Invalid write (: but it doesn't say what part or why it arises unlike mine.

Comment: If you compile with -g, then it will say where in the source the invalid write is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *segmentation fault* error could stem from `free(s)`s in both `add_user(...)` and `connect_user(...)` functions since `char s[...]` is variable sized arrays on the stack, not allotted to the heap to be `free`d. You need to get rid of them.

In the server and client sides, you don't wait your child process by using `wait(..)` or `waitpid(..)`

In addition, it is better to initialize arrays with `0`s e.g. `char arr[SIZE] = {0}`, for variable-sized arrays too.

AFAI know also, `bzero` is deprecated and reduces portability. So you should use `memset(..)` instead.

`n = write(newsockfd, "See you soon!", 18);` at line 128 what about remaining `5` characters(bytes)? Garbage writings?

Better for you to use `-Weverything` flag tas well.

---

### Let's focus on the following point,

**`shared_memory[0] = 0;` ?**

What if `shm_open(..)` returns `-1`? In this case, are you sure `shared_memory` points to a legal place in which you are able to write? You should **always pay special attention to return values and their results.**

```
int shm_fd = shm_open("Transmitting", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
    if (shm_fd == -1) {
        perror("shm_fd error");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

In my computer, it yields that `shm_fd error: File exists` after one-time running inherently.

AFAI remember, non-anonymous shared mapping object stays in the computer unless it is removed by hand or by `unlink(..)` or `remove(..)`

Or, just remove `O_EXCL` flag.

Comment: I got rid of them but it still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @jipthechip Did you look at the below part of the answer?

Comment: Ah, I see what the issue was now. What happened was I mapped the memory location and didn't call ```unlink``` the first time so when I went to map it on the second execution it seg faulted. But this means that if the client process unexpectedly terminates, this will happen again. How would I check if the location is mapped and then unlink it if it is?

Comment: @jipthechip When a TCP connection is closed on one side `read()` on the other side returns `0` byte. Besides, you know on the both side name of the shared memory.